# protected routes in react js app always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

here is my protectedroute component
am using react-router-dom v6 and accessing the token from localStorage
and either ways user is always returning undefined

```
import { Outlet, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const userAuth = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/isUserAuth", {
      headers: {
      "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
    }}).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      if(response.data.auth) {
        console.log(true)
        return true;
        
      } else {
        console.log(false)
        return false;
      }
    })
  }

  let auth = userAuth()
  console.log("auth",auth)

  return (
    auth? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/"/>
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

my app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <ToastContainer position='top-center'/>
        <Routes>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes/>}>
              <Route exact path='/home' 
                element={< Home />}/> 
              <Route exact path='/add' 
                element={< AddCust />} /> 
              <Route exact path='/update/:id' 
                element={< AddCust />} /> 
              <Route exact path='/view/:id' 
                element={< View />} /> 
              <Route exact path='/table' 
                element={< Table />} /> 
              <Route exact path='/edit-order/:id' 
                element={< Table />} /> 
                <Route exact path='/orders' 
                element={< Orders />} /> 
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/' element={< Login />} /> 
              
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is what is consoled logged
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VoC4.png)

which is weired whether a token exists or not auth is always undefined

Comment: You are never returning anything from `userAuth` you are only returning from anonymous functions that you created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is actually returned from the `userAuth` function, so `auth` is `undefined`. While you *could* return the `axios` Promise object, this will make `userAuth` an asynchronous function and not usable as a ternary condition to conditionally render the `Outlet` component or redirect.

A solution then is to convert `auth` to a React state, updated in the GET request flow, and conditionally render `null` or a loading indicator until the auth status resolves.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(); // initially undefined

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:5000/isUserAuth",
          {
            headers: {
              "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
          }
        );

        setAuth(!!response.data.auth);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle error, log, etc...
        setAuth(false);
      }
    };

     checkAuth();
  }, [pathname]); // trigger auth check on route change

  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return auth
    ? <Outlet/>
    : <Navigate to="/" replace state={{ from: pathname }} />;
};
```